# useState not updating properly with axios and Promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have this code:

```
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false);

  const onSubmitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}users/auth/sign_in`,
      data: { email, password },
      headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        setSuccess(true);
        console.log(response, ' sucesso');
        const authData = {
          accessToken: response.headers['access-token'],
          client: response.headers.client,
          uid: response.headers.uid,
        };
        localStorage.setItem('authData', JSON.stringify(authData));
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        setLoading(false);
        setError(true);
        console.log(error, 'error');
      });
  };

if(success) return <Redirect to="/" />
```

It is a login page and this function gets executed when the user press the Login button. It works just fine but I'm having some trouble to make it redirect to the main page.

I have added a `success` const as `useState` and everytime the request is successful, it was supposed to set `success` to true with `setSuccess(true)` and redirect the user to `/` using `react-router-dom` but it is not working. The state still as false. What I'm doing wrong?

I have also tried using `useEffect` like this:

```
  const returnFunc = () => <Redirect to="/" />;
  useEffect(() => {
    if (success) {
      returnFunc();
    }
  }, [success, loading]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just do:

```
useEffect(() => {}, [success, loading]);

if(success) return <Redirect to="/" />
```

If you are calling your returnFunc() in the UseState it is not going to work, just with nothing inside the UseEffect but only [success] is going to re-render the page because you set success to true and then it should take you to the main page.

Comment: for some reason, it works 2 times and then it starts doing nothing. The response from the login api is 200 but no redirect is made

Comment: It redirected you 2 times on the main page?

Comment: It works for one time, then I logout and when I try again, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
return success ? <Redirect to="/" /> : "Render somthing for none login state";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

...
return (
  ...
  <Router>
   {success && <Redirect to="/" />}
  </Router>
)



// or you can try this way
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

let history = useHistory();
...

useEffect(() => {
    if (success) {
      setSuccess(false)
      history.push('/');
    }
  }, [success]);
```

Comment: the second way is throwing a loop error(maximum update depth exceeded)

Comment: replace `if (success) {
      history.push('/');
    }` to `if (success) { setSuccess(false);
      history.push('/');
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed adding `window.location.href = '/';` to the `.then` and added an if to check if there is localStorage.

```
  if (localStorage.getItem('authData')) {
    return <Redirect to="/" />;
  }
```